# how to create a div background that is bigger than its container

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, ribbon, css-shapes

what would the best way to create a div that overlaps its parent container.  im using bootstrap and want to create a banner that goes larger than its container, i want to create the following:

[image]

This is the code i have so far:

```
<div class="container container-white no-pd">

        <div class="service-banner">
            <div class="text-center">
                Headline title here <a href="#" title="title" class="btn btn-default">Our Services</a>
            </div>
        </div><!--/service banner-->

    </div><!--/container-->
```

This gives me the following:

[image]

any advice?

Comment: can you show your css. also see these articles for similar effects    http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/ribbon/    http://codepen.io/jeffpowrs/pen/oaLul you should be able to extract some of the styling

Comment: Try adding `overflow: visible` to your css.

Comment: add z-index:9999; etc in your white bg div

Comment: Can you provide a jsfiddle or codepen? It makes it easier for us to find a solution.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/jbutler483/bqqbdfmc/

Comment: Thank you i will try all of the suggestions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use pseudo elements for this sort of functionality:

```css
.gray{
    height:300px;
    width:100px;
    background:darkgray;
    position:relative;
}
.banner{
    position:absolute;
    width:350px;
    height:100px;
    background:blue;
    top:20px;
    left:80px;
}
.banner:after{
    position:absolute;
    content:"";
    height:0px;
    width:0px;
    border-left:20px solid transparent;
    border-top:20px solid gray;
    bottom:-20px;
    left:0;
}
```

```html
<div class="gray">
    <div class="banner">Heading here</div>
</div>
```

Please Note the following for further understanding:

- I've been able to use the `top`, `bottom`, `left` and `right` properties in my css since I have set that element to `position:absolute;`. When an element is positioned like this, It means they can be manipulated using these.
- It's also important to note how i made the 'triangle shadow'. This was achieved through using the 'border hack', in which allows you to set a transparent border, and a 'coloured one' in order to make this: [*see here for more info about this*](http://appendto.com/2013/03/pure-css-triangles-explained/).
- pseudo elements need to contain a `content` and usually are positioned `absolutely` in order for you to position them nicely in your markup.

Comment: only now im trying the code, is there any way to use this with a responsive framework such as bootstrap?

Comment: @Ricky: I would *really* avoid bootstrap.